# Handling concurrent reading/writing of a file

Tags: c#, .net

I have a web service that is generating random errors and I think I've found the fault.

Basically, it is reading a config file as follows, then loaded into an XmlDocument:

```
var config = File.ReadAllText(filename);
xmlDoc.Load(config);
```

However, at a later time (maybe a second later) one of the config values is updated and the file saved

```
xmlDoc.Save(filename);
```

So I'm now experiencing more errors (unfortunately the original developer added an empty try block so I can't check just now) during the first READ operation and I think it's because it's trying to read the file just as another process spawned from IIS is at the .Save part. I don't know how File.ReadAllText works and whether it will fail on a write locked file.

What's the best solution to handle this to ensure reading will always work? the value being written is just a counter and if it fails it is ignored as it's not that important but would prefer it was written. I guess I could put it into a separate config file and live with the error but I'd rather it was just one file.

Thanks.

Comment: Use a lock() with an static object to ensure only one thread can access the file at the same time.

Comment: Thanks. Would that be the standard way to do it in my IIS web-service, assuming lots of processes wanting to read and write at the same time continuously? Am I right in my assumption, btw, of writing locking a read?

Comment: @gusman The OP thinks that the reads are from different processes rather than different threads so it would need a mutex rather than a lock

Comment: @Goodwin, yes I guess you're right. I just want a simple solution to it not failing when reading a config file :)

Comment: @MikeGoodwin I think the user just got wrong how IIS works, IIS doesn't spawn new processes but threads, so the lock() would work unless the user is doing something special. In that case yes, he should use a mutex, and a named one. But mutex with IIS give a hard time as my experience, at least with IIS7 was very easy to get it hung with no reason at all.

Comment: Perhaps I'm not thinking how quick things are. If my webservice is under continuous load would all the locks manage themselves nicely enough to not end up stuck? If so, is there a best practise bit of code you could put in an answer please :)

Comment: As @gusman suggests, the correct approach depends on whether the reads/writes need to be synchronised across processes (needs a mutex) or just threads (needs a lock). Can you confirm which it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a lock to make sure that a read is completed before a write and vice verser. As in:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

class Program
{
    static readonly object _fileAccess = new object();

    static void Write()
    {
        // Obtain lock and write
        lock (_fileAccess)
        {
            // Write data to filename
            xmlDoc.Save(filename);
        }
    }

    static void Read()
    {
        // Obtain lock and read
        lock (_fileAccess)
        {
            // Read some data from filename
            xmlDoc.load(filename);
        }
    }

    static void Main()
    {       
        ThreadStart writeT = new ThreadStart(Write);
        new Thread(writeT).Start();

        ThreadStart readT = new ThreadStart(Read);
        new Thread(readT).Start();
    }
}
```

With the lock, the Read() must wait for the Write() to complete and Write() must wait for Read() to complete.

Comment: Thanks. So I don't need to separate out my config for the read only and writable elements, as I was thinking of doing that. Also, I take it this will work across the many threads IIS application pool might be creating for simultaneous requests and wherever I read or write my config in code I use the thread start instead of simply calling it?

Comment: Yes you don't need to separate them out. And locks are thread safe by design, also notice the locked object is static so only one instance of it will exist through the app life cycle. Thread start would do also

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question about how `File.ReadAllText()` works, looking at the source, it uses a `StreamReader` internally which in turn uses a `FileStream` opened with  `FileAccess.Read` and `FileShare.Read`, so that would prevent any other process from writing to the file (e.g. your `XmlDocument.Save()`) until the `ReadAllText` completed.

Meanwhile, your `XmlDocument.Save()` eventually uses `FileStream` opened with
`FileAccess.Write` and `FileShare.Read`, so it would allow the `File.ReadAllText()` as long as the `Save` started before the `ReadAllText`.

References: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs,a820588d8233a829

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Dom/XmlDocument.cs,1db4dba15523d588

Comment: Thanks for taking the time out. So maybe I'm looking in the wrong place as using your link I saw XmlWriter has a FileShare. Read the same as the reader so it shouldn't be failing. It's just that is where the code is pointing me at :(

Comment: They both have `FileShare.Read` but `XmlDocument.Save()` has `FileAccess.Write` so if it tries to open while the `ReadAllText` is still executing it will fail. So many writes/reads/fileaccess/fileshares - it's a bit confusing :o)